# Charfield null errors

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have setup a model with a couple of Charfield set as blank=True rather than null as per two scoops book advice (section 6.2.4).

```
class Supplier(models.Model):
    unique_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    supplier_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

However when I try to save a model entry which has a None to the supplier_name field I get an error:
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "supplier_name" violates not-null constraint.
What's the best approach to deal with this? Should I just use null=True in the field declaration or convert the None to empty string (not ideal)? Or another approach?

Comment: How are you creating the `Supplier` instance? If you don't specify the `supplier_name`, e.g. `Supplier.objects.create(unique_id=1, name='example')`, then I would expect `supplier_name` to be saved as an empty string. However, if you explicitly set `supplier_name=None` e.g. `Supplier.objects.create(unique_id=2, name='example2', supplier_name=None)`, then Django will try to save null and you will get the `IntegrityError`. Note that the `blank=True` option affects the Django admin and model forms -- it doesn't affect the underlying database schema, or automatically convert `None` to `''`.

Comment: thanks that's the problem. I thought django did automatically convert None to '' and I have been trying to save with `supplier_name=None`

Comment: Glad it helped, I've added the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify the `supplier_name`, e.g. `Supplier.objects.create(unique_id=1, name='example')`, then I would expect `supplier_name` to be saved as an empty string.

However, if you explicitly set `supplier_name=None`, e.g.
`Supplier.objects.create(unique_id=2, name='example2', supplier_name=None)`, then Django will try to save null and you will get the `IntegrityError`.

Note that the blank=True option affects model forms and the Django admin. It doesn't affect the underlying database schema, or automatically convert `None` to `''`.

The reason that Two Scoops and the Django Docs recommend `null=False` is so that `''` is the only value for 'no data'. If you have `null=True` then there are two values for 'no data', `''` and `None`.

One good reason to use `null=True` is if you want to make the field unique, but allow empty values.

In your case, it's hard to say what you should do because you haven't shown the code. Ideally, keep `null=True` to stick with the Django convention. You could then modify your code so that you don't set `supplier_name=None`, or convert it with `supplier_name = supplier_name or ''`.

Answer (score 0):

If your fine with keeping that field as null then use `null=True` another advantage of using null=true you will not fetch future updation error when ever you will add other filed in your same model then every time you need to tell for `default` value so it's better to use null=true to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a null value, provide a default value to the field:

```
supplier_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', blank=True)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#default